# Stat command returning different modification date when used in pipe vs. no pipe

Tags: bash

When using

`stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d%H%M" test/0025-05-026-107339_14.PDF`

the modifcation date as shown in the finder is returned (here: 201611110137)

However, when piping in order to get the newest file in a directory; like

`ls -t $dir/0025-05*.PDF | head -1 | stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d%H%M"`

the system time is returned (here: 201701061146), even though

`ls -t $dir/0025-05*.PDF | head -1`

returns the same file (test/0025-05-026-107339_14.PDF).

What do I get wrong?

Comment: stat (GNU coreutils) 8.5 gives these two errors: `stat: cannot read file system information for '%Sm': No such file or directory` and `stat: cannot read file system information for '%Y%m%d%H%M': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stat` statement seems a bit odd, but apart from that, the pipe returns `stat: missing operand` for me. My theory is that the pipe doesn't actually provide the file itself to `stat`, only a string containing the filename, which is generated on-the-fly, which is why the system time gets returned. I would try substituting the pipe with command substitution, like this:

`stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d%H%M" $(ls -t $dir/0025-05*.PDF | head -1)`

At least it did the trick for me with a slighly differently formulated `stat` command.